# How to use store_result() to get the data?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, resultset

I'm having trouble trying to use `$stmt->store_result()` after executing a prepared statement. The manual says "Transfers a result set from a prepared statement", but to where?

I would ideally like to use it, all nice and buffered in memory, like `$mysqli->query()` returns.

The PHP documentation examples make it seem like the only good reason to use `store_result()` is to get the number of rows.

Ideally, I need something that can get the entire result set from a prepared statement and do something like fetch_rows on it. I DID hack the `mysqli_stmt` class by extending it and adding a `fetch_assoc` function using some backwards methods, but I would really like to remove that hack if I can get all my data buffered into memory.

So I guess my short question is, I know what `store_result()` does, but how do you USE it?

(And honestly, I wouldn't even be using `$mysqli->prepare()` to get a stmt, if it wasn't so damn useful in preventing SQL injection attacks, sterilizing variables, and making my SQL look so nice and pretty with all those question marks.)

Comment: Sooo.. my hacked stmt to fetch_assoc() was actually doubling my load time compared to vsprintf()'ing my sql and just passing it to mysqli->query() to get a normal result set. So i'm sticking with that for now. Too bad really, wish it worked with built in functions.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that `store_result()` does is it moves the result from MySQL into PHP memory. It's not very useful since you still need to fetch the results into PHP variables.

What you are looking for is `get_result()`. This function will fetch results from MySQL and store them in PHP memory, additionally returning a familiar `mysqli_result` object.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT ? as col');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $variable);
$stmt->execute();

// returns mysqli_result object
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// loop to get associative rows
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['col'];
}
```